# Make new char * from 1 given as argument with elements between 2 indexes

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function to create a new char array from another one given as argument, with the elements between 2 specified indexes.

```
char * split(char * array, int i, int j){
    int x = 0;
    char * newArray;
    for (int m = i; m < j; m++){
        newArray[x] = array[m];
        x++;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

For example:

```
char * s = "helloworld";
char * first = split(s, 0, 5); // 'hello'
char * second = split(s, 5, 10); // 'world'
```

But for some reason it keeps giving me segmentation fault after I try to access any of the elements of 'first' or 'second' after the function call.

Comment: `char * newArray;` this is a pointer. It is uninitialized. There is no memory behind it. `newArray[x] = ` is invalid. Where do you want to store the bytes that are in the string?

Answer (score 3):

You never allocated actual memory for `char * newArray` (or even initialized it to `NULL` or the like), so it's a garbage address pointing to unallocated memory.

The first time you do `newArray[x] = array[m];` you've invoked undefined behavior; `newArray` points to ??? and `newArray[x]` points to "`x` bytes past ???" which is still ???. You need to allocate memory yourself and store the pointer to it in `newArray` (allocate an extra byte for the `NUL` terminator), initialize it by copying (and make sure you set a `NUL` byte at the end for C-style strings), and return it.

Note that given you're using C++, you should really just be using `std::string` and its `substr` method and saving yourself a lot of headaches.